# Implementing a readonly hashable set in C#

Tags: c#, set, constants, readonly

Some of the dialogue from this question turned ugly and it was requested that I ask a new question, but because there is an answer, I cannot delete it despite the similarity (pretty lame, Stackoverflow).

**Please see this question:**

[Implementing a content-hashable HashSet in C# (like python's `frozenset`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912642/implementing-a-content-hashable-hashset-in-c-sharp-like-pythons-frozenset)

Comment: Be aware that the ordering of an `HashSet` isn't stable, so depending on how you built the `ToString()`, equal `HashSet` could have different ordered enumerations.

Comment: @xanatos Good point, it is also sorted.

Comment: the easiest way to calculate the GetHashCode is to simply xor (^) all the gethashcodes of the elements. The xor operator is commutative, so the ordering is irrelevant. For the comparison you can use the `SetEquals`

Comment: Thank you kind raccoon. But do you have any solution to the design problem posed in the question? Computing the hash code is not really where I am stuck

Comment: If you want a read only set just encapsulate a `HashSet` in a new type that takes all items in it's constructor and only exposes non-mutable members, possibly with some sort of method that creates a new mutable set with the same items if you need to get back a mutable set with the same data later on.

Comment: "As far as I know, extensions would not apply.": The common extension methods (I'm assuming that's what you meant) are implemented for interfaces, so as long as your `ContentHashableHashSet` implements the same interface as `HashSet` (`ISet<T>`), extension methods should continue to work.

Comment: @hvd Very good point. That might tip the scales to wrapping a readonly HashSet. Care to write this answer (obviously does not need to implement every method) and collect the bounty?

Comment: By the time I got around to reading that, Hans Passant posted a probably better answer. :)

Answer (score 6):

You need an `ImmutableHashSet<>`.  Your timing is good, it is available through NuGet in the [Microsoft.Collections.Immutable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/) package.

For background, see [Preview of Immmutable Collections Released on NuGet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx).  The video [Inside Immutable Collections](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Immo-Landwerth-and-Andrew-Arnott-Inside-Immutable-Collections) is also available.

Comment: I still wouldn't mind learning how I would design this myself (as a good lesson in design), but your answer definitely solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: N.B. ImmutableHashSet is sealed (does anyone know why?). Thus, it is impossible to derive from it and override `GetHashCode()`... Back to square one.

Comment: You don't need that.  HashSet has a constructor that takes an IEqualityComparer.

Comment: And how do you force ImmutableHashSet to generate a hash code based on the content of the set?

Comment: You don't, you implement it yourself.  GetHashCode() must be fast or it entirely loses its benefit.  That's of course always an issue with collections, you don't want to have to iterate the entire collection to calculate the hash.  So don't, return the Count property value for a very fast hash.  Please click the Ask Question button for follow-up questions, this one is wearing me out.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding: I want a content-hashable HashSet. This can be performed by 1) using a type like ImmutableHashSet and the 2)n implementing a content-specific GetHashCode method. I was grateful for your recommendation of an available ImmutableHashSetClass, but I couldn't use it because it is sealed, and so I cannot (to my knowledge) derive from it and implement my own override `GetHashCode`. So I still cannot make HashSet<ContentHashableHashSet<T>> that uses the set *contents*. Can you see why, to me, this is not a follow up question, but is clearly stated in the original?

Comment: Who says you need to inherit and override? Pass a custom `IEqualityComparer<ContentHashableHashSet<T>>` [to the outer HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359100.aspx), like Hans says. Though I am very curious- what problem are you solving by maintaining a hashset of hashsets?

Comment: But I don't need the "changes to the HashSet replace it with a new copy" aspect of `ImmutableHashSet`. I just want the darn thing to be read-only. Isn't there something better for that purpose?