# Implementing a content-hashable HashSet in C# (like python's `frozenset`)

Tags: c#, set, containers, immutability

**Brief summary**

I want to build a set of sets of items in C#. The inner sets of items have a `GetHashCode` and `Equals` method defined by their *contents*. In mathematical notation:

```
x = { }
x.Add( { A, B, C } )
x.Add( { A, D } )
x.Add( { B, C, A } )

now x should be{ { A, B, C }, { A, D } }
```

In python, this could be accomplished with `frozenset`:

```
x = set()
x.add( frozenset(['A','B','C']) )
x.add( frozenset(['A','D']) )
x.add( frozenset(['B','C','A']) )
```

**/BriefSummary**

I would like to have a hashable HashSet in C#. This would allow me to do:

```
HashSet<ContentHashableHashSet<int>> setOfSets;
```

Although there are more sophisticated ways to accomplish this, This can be trivially achieved in practice (although not in the most efficient manner) by adding overriding `ContentHashableHashSet.ToString()` (outputing the strings of the elements contained in sorted order) and then using then using `ContentHashableHashSet.ToString().GetHashCode()` as the hash code.

However, if an object is modified after placement in `setOfSets`, it could result in multiple copies:

```
var setA = new ContentHashableHashSet<int>();
setA.Add(1);
setA.Add(2);
var setB = new ContentHashableHashSet<int>();
setB.Add(1);

setOfSets.Add(setA);
setOfSets.Add(setB);

setB.Add(2); // now there are duplicate members!
```

As far as I can see, I have two options: I can derive `ContentHashableHashSet` from `HashSet`, but then I will need to make it so that all modifiers throw an exception. Missing one modifier could cause an insidious bug.

Alternatively, I can use encapsulation and class `ContentHashableHashSet` can contain a `readonly HashSet`. But then I would need to reimplement all set methods (except modifiers) so that the `ContentHashableHashSet` can behave like a `HashSet`. As far as I know, extensions would not apply.

Lastly, I could encapsulate as above and then all set-like functionality will occur by returning the const (or readonly?) HashSet member.

In hindsight, this is reminiscent of python's `frozenset`. Does anyone know of a well-designed way to implement this in C#?

If I was able to lose `ISet` functionality, then I would simply create a sorted `ImmutableList`, but then I would lose functionality like fast union, fast intersection, and sub-linear ( roughly O(log(n)) )  set membership with `Contains`.

**EDIT:** The base class HashSet does *not* have virtual `Add` and `Remove` methods, so overriding them will work within the derived class, but will *not* work if you perform `HashSet<int> set = new ContentHashableHashSet<int>();`. Casting to the base class will allow editing.

**EDIT 2:** Thanks to @xanatos for recommending a simple `GetHashCode` implementation:

> The easiest way to calculate the GetHashCode is to simply xor (^) all the gethashcodes of the elements. The xor operator is commutative, so the ordering is irrelevant. For the comparison you can use the SetEquals

**EDIT 3:** Someone recently shared information about [ImmutableHashSet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx), but because this class is sealed, it is not possible to derive from it and override `GetHashCode`.

I was also told that `HashSet` takes an `IEqualityComparer` as an argument, and so this can be used to provide an immutable, content-hashable set without deriving from ImmutableHashSet; however, this is not a very object oriented solution: every time I want to use a `ContentHashableHashSet`, I will need to pass the same (non-trivial) argument. As I'm sure you know, this can really wreak havoc with your coding zen, and where I would be flying along in python with `myDictionary[ frozenset(mySet) ] = myValue`, I will be stuck doing the same thing [again and again and again](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus).

Thanks for any help you can provide. I have a temporary workaround (whose problems are mentioned in **EDIT 1** above), but I'd mostly like to learn about the best way to design something like this.

Comment: What I did in such situation was to create `IReadOnlySet<T> : IReadOnlyCollection<T>` interface, where I would re-declare non-mutating set methods, as well as changing the contract on some of the methods to not modify the set, but return a new one (e.g. `IReadOnlySet<T> SymmetricExceptWith(IEnumerable<T> other);
`). It's not exactly 'backwards-compatible' and there's a lot of delegation, but the interface is simple.

Comment: Wow. Probably worth re-checking your architecture to see if you can find a simpler and cleaner way to do whatever you need to do. However in this case I am not even sure what the question is exactly. Are you not just struggling with hash key generation?

Comment: @dr.mo It isn't `GetHashCode` that's the problem (that's easy-- use `ToString().GetHashCode()`), it's the fact that the set of items can change after insertion into the set of sets of items, and this change may result in duplicate sets of items.

Comment: If you're ok with the overhead, simply have a wrapper class round the outer set that copies your hashset on Add, and also copies any retrieved values. Then no-one can modify a hashset that's been added to your outer set. What operations do you need on the outer set (`x` in your example)? I only see `Add`, but presumably you want `contains`, `get`, etc?

Comment: @oliver can you rewrite the class so it's immutable? I.e take a list of ints as argument to the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Hide the elements of your set of sets so that they can't be changed. That means copying when you add/retrieve sets, but maybe that's acceptable?

```
// Better make sure T is immutable too, else set hashes could change
public class SetofSets<T>
{
    private class HashSetComparer : IEqualityComparer<HashSet<T>>
    {
        public int GetHashCode(HashSet<T> x)
        {
            return x.Aggregate(1, (code,elt) => code ^ elt.GetHashCode());
        }

        public bool Equals(HashSet<T> x, HashSet<T> y)
        {
            if (x==null)
                return y==null;
            return x.SetEquals(y);
        }
    }

    private HashSet<HashSet<T>> setOfSets;
    public SetofSets()
    {
        setOfSets = new HashSet<HashSet<T>>(new HashSetComparer());
    }

    public void Add(HashSet<T> set)
    {
        setOfSets.Add(new HashSet<T>(set));
    }

    public bool Contains(HashSet<T> set)
    {
        return setOfSets.Contains(set);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Elegant. This is along the lines of how I'm thinking. It does solve the specific set-of-sets problem, but I would I be able to reuse code when making a `Dictionary<HashSet, ...>`?

Comment: You can use the same idea to implement `IDictionary<HashSet<T>,U>`. You can move the HashSetComparer outside the class and share it - there's no reason for it to be private inside the SetOfSets class. Not sure what else there is to reuse - you're simply implementing the `IDictionary` members by passing calls through to a privately held `Dictionary`, but ensuring you copy any hashset on the way in (e.g. Add, []) or out (e.g. Keys,Trygetvalue,[])

Comment: Ah, this is what I'm missing: I won't be able to use .UnionWith, etc. without reimplementing all of those methods and calling the appropriate method with setOfSets?

Comment: Do you want to use UnionWith on your hashset (inner set)? Or your SetOfSets/DictionaryOfSets (outer set)? You only need to provide implementation for the outer set. You can use all existing hashset functionality unchanged on your inner hashset. Note however that if you add X to the SetOfSets, then modify X by performing UnionWith, the copy of X that is in the SetOfSets is unchanged. You've only modified the version you're holding. In that sense, the copy of X in the SetOfSets is effectively immutable.